# issues with writing Chinese to csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, output

I am a python beginner here. Recently I have been trying to scrape some data from a local Chinese website.
I successfully stored the information as a matrix (list of list),c, but when I was tring to write it into a csv file I have got some messy stuff. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
url = "http://wszw.hzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecp/fem/corp/fem_cert_stat_view_list.jsp"
r=requests.get(url)
data= r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data) 

table = soup.find_all('table')[3]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
dogData= 0
c=[]
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.find_all('td')
    dogName =cols[0].get_text()
    rank2013 = cols[1].get_text()
    rank2012 =cols[2].get_text()
    rank2008 =cols[3].get_text()
    rank2003 =cols[4].get_text()
    rank2004 =cols[5].get_text()
    rank2005=cols[6].get_text()
    temp=[dogName,rank2013,rank2012,rank2008,rank2003,rank2004,rank2005]
    [x.encode('gb18030') for x in temp]
    c.append(temp)



with open("output.csv", "wt") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(c)
```

I am using Python 3.4
Can anyone tell me what went wrong and how can I improve the code? Thanks so much!
Marco

Comment: what exactly is [x.encode('gb18030') for x in temp] doing? It's list comprehension, but it's not assigned to a variable. Basically that line of code is doing nothing, because you're not passing it to a variable to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run your code, but I did notice something odd. 
You typed

```
temp=[dogName,rank2013,rank2012,rank2008,rank2003,rank2004,rank2005]
[x.encode('gb18030') for x in temp]
c.append(temp)
```

however `[x.encode('gb18030') for x in temp]` isn't doing anything.  Right now, the code you wrote is the same as:

```
temp=[dogName,rank2013,rank2012,rank2008,rank2003,rank2004,rank2005]
c.append(temp)
```

If you want to use list comprehension the way you're using it:

```
temp=[dogName,rank2013,rank2012,rank2008,rank2003,rank2004,rank2005]
modified_temp = [x.encode('gb18030') for x in temp]
c.append(modified_temp)
```

Comment: Hello msanti, You are right there is a mistake here. I changed the code according to your suggestion but now I am getting the raw gb18030 code in the csv file. What I want actually is to print out Chinese characters in the csv file. Is there anyway to do that? I searched online and they suggest using the module codecs but I have no idea how to implement this. Can you give me some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You might want to do some research. The issue is how you're encoding the data. Here is a suggest link to study http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174260/reading-chinese-characters-in-a-file-and-sending-them-to-a-browser, or you may want to find an API that handles Chinese characters

Comment: Thanks! I have figured it out. Now instead of output as lists, I write as elements, which works fine. I appreciate your help.