# write chinese words in csv file using python2.7

Tags: python-unicode

I am trying to write Chinese words like 花花公子昊天鞋类专营店 in a CSV file in python, but not able to do it. I tried solution given here("[issues with writing Chinese to csv file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442448/issues-with-writing-chinese-to-csv-file-in-python)"). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `unicodecsv` helps with that (you can install that with **pip**):

```
import unicodecsv
w = unicodecsv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))
w.writerow((u"花花公子昊天鞋类专营店", 78.10))
del w
```

The resulting csv file opens succesfully in OpenOffice.

You can also read it back in Python:

```
r = unicodecsv.reader(open("test.csv", "rb"))
for row in r:
    print row[0], row[1]
```

And when run, it should print:

```
(user@motoom) ~/Prj/python $ python chinesecsv.py

花花公子昊天鞋类专营店 78.1
```

Comment: I tried your code, with same Chinese word. But I found this èŠ±èŠ±å…¬å­æ˜Šå¤©éž‹ç±»ä¸“è¥åº—  in my CSV file instead of 花花公子昊天鞋类专营店

Comment: With what application did you open the CSV file? If that application doesn't recognize it as UTF8-encoded, you'll get the gibberish you show above.

Comment: I added some code to the example to read and print the resulting CSV.

Comment: When I open the CSV in an application which assumes that the file is encoded with Windows 1251 encoding, I also get `èŠ±èŠ±å…¬å­?æ˜Šå¤©éž‹ç±»ä¸“è?¥åº—,78.1`, so that might be your problem.  Try to open the CSV with an application which can interpret UTF8-encoding.

Comment: oh yes. This was the problem. Thank you Michiel.